# How to show that each of the following sets is many-one equivalent to $K$? [cutland 9-2.9-1]

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, computational-mathematics

(a) {$x:x\in E_x$}

(b) {$x:\phi_x (x)=0$}

I know how to show **$K≤_m$ {$x:x\in E_x$}**, and **$K≤_m$ {$x:\phi_x (x)=0$}** by s-m-n.

But I don't know how to show that **{$x:x\in E_x$}$≤_m$ $K$**, and **{$x:\phi_x (x)=0$}$≤_m K$**

Comment: What are $E_x$ and $\phi_x(x)$?

Comment: @coffeemath $E_x$ is the range of $\phi_x$. $\phi_x$ is the unary URM-computable function whose indice is x.